# running fabfile task from django

Tags: django, fabric

I have a fabric task eg-

```
def run_task():

#code here
```

From the command prompt I run this task:

```
fab -c env.fabricrc run_task -H hostnamr
```

How can I run this task from django?I click on a  button on a webpage in django app and it should do this.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the section](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/usage/library.html) on how to use fabric as a python module/library without using the fab command to run tasks.

Short example:

```
from fabric.api import execute
#import your task if it is not in the same module, i.e.:
from mytasks import run_task

execute(run_task, hosts='hostname')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should place this logic somewhere in your Django app. And let `run_task` be just a wrapper around this logic.

It is fabfile that's based on the app, not vise versa.